# Unable to connect to Stream when setting up new workspace

Tags: perforce, p4v

When setting up a new workspace within P4V, I am unable to connect to a Stream.

`Connection -> New Workspace` opens the new workspace dialog box, but the `Stream` option is disabled.

The issue appears to be client side, because others in the team do not have this issue.

The P4V version is :
*Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX86/2012.1/490402*

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a specific stream you can't connect to? Or you can't connect to any streams at all? If the stream you're having trouble with is a Task Stream, that functionality wasn't added to P4V until the 2013.1 version. But if you just can't connect to streams at all, then you probably have a different problem. What version of P4V are the other members of your team using?

Comment: Can't connect to any stream at all Bryan, because the Stream picker is disabled. I'll check which version of p4v the others are on

Comment: checked - the p4v version is the same

Comment: If you use the 'p4' command line, rather than the P4V tool, can you see the streams? (e.g., run 'p4 streams' from the command line).

Comment: 'p4v streams' on command line throws error "P4V: unrecognized option 'streams'

Comment: Correct. The 'p4' command line client is different than the 'p4v' GUI client, so 'p4 streams' was not a typo in my previous comment. When you ran the 'p4v' installer, I believe it also installed the 'p4' command line client, but if it didn't you can get the 'p4' command line client from the Perforce web site.

Comment: 'p4 streams' outputs 'No such stream.'

Comment: If there are no streams in the server, then it's no surprise that you can't create a workspace for a stream. You'd have to create the stream first. Are you sure you're connecting to the same server that your other team members are? Do they also see 'no such stream' when they look at the streams in the server?

Comment: 'p4 streams' returns nothing for me, but others see a list of streams, including '//sXXX/dev'. When I enter: 'p4 -t development //sXXX/dev', notepad opens with the configuration of the stream as it has been setup and as it is being used by others.

Comment: Perhaps it's a permissions thing. Maybe your administrator has not granted you the permissions to read the other streams. Ask your administrator to check the protections table.